# How to remove store code when changing store views?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, url, store-view, store-switcher

So I've setup multiple views for my website, but the thing is, when I change store views, the URL ends up looking like this:

> https://www.domain.com/shop/product1.html?___store=english&___from_store=hindi

I'd like to be like:

> https://www.domain.com/shop/product1.html

Any suggestions on how to do this?

P.S. I have set the option to '**add code to the URL**' as **No**.

Comment: which magento version have you used ?

Comment: @DharmendraJadav 2.2.5

Comment: Did you remove generated and var folder?

Comment: @RohanHapani I have mutliple views. I need my website in english and hindi, and I need to be able to switch between them. The URL changes only when I switch views.

Not sure how deletion of var and generated folders would help? But if it does, do tell. I'd like to know.

Comment: Please run command "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" and then clear cache than after check.

Comment: Add store code to url is a different thing. This doesn't mean it will not show store views. If you enable store code to url that means your url will be like https://www.domain.com/en/shop/product.html or https://www.domain.com/nl/shop/product.html or https://www.domain.com/pr/shop/product.html etc.

Comment: @SukumarGorai Got it. Any suggestions for the URL problem?

Comment: You can customize that with form with post values should not include parameters to the ulr. Magento uses get parameters in case of language translation.